# Keep one element on top of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have an HTML/DOM element that I need to stay positioned above another element, regardless of where and when the target element moves.

For various (and unfortunate) reasons, I can't do this through simple CSS relative positioning. The element that I want to reposition can't be an immediate child of the parent of the target element. (It needs to be several layers up in fact, though both elements do share a common ancestor.)

I can position the element over the target element easily using jQuery's offset() functions. However, if the target element moves, the repositioned element doesn't follow. Changing the browser dimensions is one way (and the primary way I care about) this can happen; the layout changes which causes the target element's offset to change.

Here's the rough structure of my document:

```
<div id="common-ancestor">
  <div id="to-reposition-container">
    <div id="to-reposition"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="some-stuff-in-between"></div>
  <div id="target-container">
    <div id="target"></div>
  <div>
</div>
```

I want `#to-reposition` to be visually placed over top of `#target` without changing the DOM tree. I cannot absolutely position `#target` outside of the natural bounds of `#target-container`.

I'm open to solutions that use CSS, JavaScript, and/or jQuery.

Comment: Maybe you can use the common ancestor as an anchor. However, the solution depends on the specific layout - I think you should provide more info about the layout.

Comment: Please provide some example code and show us what you have tried.

Comment: @nedk: All I did was a jQuery one-time reposition: `$("#to-reposition").offset($("#target").offset());` This worked fine until the page size changed. Then `target`'s offsets changed, and I realized I'd have to change `to-reposition`'s offsets too.

Comment: Updated to add an example DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repositioning the element the same way you did originally within a window resize event handler should work, but it certainly won't handle other cases, such as font size changes and scrolling.  I don't think there's any sort of layout changing event, so if you want to catch all cases of the element's moving, you'd unfortunately have to constantly reposition in a timer event.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. :-P

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but it'll do the trick:

```
$(window).bind('resize',function() {/* reposition using offset */});
```

The better way is to use css (since that would also work in none-resize scenarios)

With the supplied markup i'd suggest setting `#common-ancestor { position: relative; }` and then absolutely position #to-reposition-container & #target-container on top of eachother, from there it should not be a problem for you.

Comment: NOTE: The behaviour of this event differs between browsers. Some fire the event continuously, some only after the resize event has completed. This changes the user experience.

Comment: very true, resize works best if you debounce the eventhandler